# cannot install datetime picker module on angularjs app

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

Most of the datetime picker I have tried to install are not working on my app due the incompatibility of angular versions and ui-bootstrap.
I am using angularjs 1.2.16 which is quite old and seems kinda difficult to find a compatible datetime picker for this version.

My bower.json looks as below

```
{
  "name": "app",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "dependencies": {
    "angular": "1.2.16",
    "json3": "~3.3.1",
    "es5-shim": "~3.1.0",
    "angular-resource": "1.2.16",
    "angular-cookies": "1.2.16",
    "angular-sanitize": "1.2.16",
    "angular-animate": "1.2.16",
    "angular-touch": "1.2.16",
    "angular-route": "1.2.16",
    "font-awesome": "4.3.0",
    "angular-bootstrap": "0.12.0",
    "oclazyload": "~0.5.2",
    "angular-loading-bar": "~0.7.0",
    "angular-ui-router": "~0.2.13",
    "angular-toggle-switch": "~1.2.1",
    "metisMenu": "~1.1.3",
    "angular-chart.js": "~0.5.2",
    "satellizer": "~0.13.1",
    "angular-payments": "*",
    "angular-file-upload": "~2.2.0",
    "bootstrap-select": "~1.9.3",
    "ngBootbox": "~0.1.3",
    "angular-ui-tinymce": "~0.0.12"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "angular-mocks": "1.2.16",
    "angular-scenario": "1.2.16"
  },
  "resolutions": {
    "angular": "^1.1.5",
    "bootstrap": "~3.1.1",
    "angular-sanitize": "1.2.16"
  },
  "appPath": "app"
}
```

Is there any date time picker for this version, or what would you suggest me to do at this time?

Comment: you can try pickaday, it's javascript based only but easy to implement.

Comment: can I use it within angularjs app, if so, is there any sample?

Comment: this is working great, thnx, also is it date time picker all in one?

Comment: @z.a. do u by anychance know how to change the format of date when selecting a date on calendar?

Comment: for that, have a look at momentjs.  it will save a lot of time for you.

Comment: do I need to install it as a seperate module, or is it inside pikaday module? do u have any example how to use that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pikaday js library, https://github.com/dbushell/Pikaday

Momentjs for date manipulation, http://momentjs.com/

Comment: I am kinda confused how do I use momentjs to format my date input.. do u have any sample?

Comment: you know, the moment comes and you kinda have to figure out on your own.  it's called learning...  thanks for accepting the answer! :)